# How to provide custom athentication/authorization manager in Wildfly

Tags: rest, security, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have a backend REST service providing authentication and authorization. How can I configure my Wildfly server or the deployed application so that the REST calls are made to verify any user credentials and retrieve user roles over REST? The application itself can access the REST service.

I try to authenticate the user by calling javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.login(username, password).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/creating-a-custom-jboss-login-module
Try create custom login module